# Why was this question (356778) closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[Can data tapes be recorded/played on a standard cassette recorder?](https://superuser.com/questions/356778/can-data-tapes-be-recorded-played-on-a-standard-cassette-recorder) was closed as off-topic.
I can see why someone would think that this is about a tape recorder ("electronic devices") but in the FAQ it says "...except insofar as they interface with your computer", and my question was about a computer (TRS-80) interfacing with it.

Is the TRS-80 not considered a "computer" on SuperUser or is there another reason why this was closed?

Comment: [Relevant Meta topic that supports your case](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2943/vintage-computer-on-topic). I don't think that capabilities and use cases of these devices was considered in that topic though, something that is, IMO, the major blocker against considering Android/iOS devices computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I voted for the same reason as Daniel. We traditionally classify PCs and Macs as computers, and we generally [have no problem with home networking equipment](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3570/update-the-faq-to-specifically-allow-home-networking-questions).

I wasn't aware of the community decision here, which did not receive any downvotes:

- [Vintage computer on-topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2943/vintage-computer-on-topic)

However, at that time, nobody mentioned Android and iPads. A more recent question would argue against this (if we say that an Android Tablet is *not* a computer, why should the TRS-80 be?):

- [How is the term “Computer” defined on Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3306/48078)

I am still torn over this, but stand by my decision to close it, as this is merely an electronic device (although considered a "computer" back then) and *very very* localized.

Comment: I suppose the TRS PC-1 does bear more resemblance to a tablet (such as iOS/Android devices) than to, for example, similar 'desktop' machines of the time (such as the TRS I or Commodores)

Comment: Yes, you're right. This can be argued (like with the ability to connect an actual keyboard and the possibilities to do other stuff you'd normally do on a computer). I'm not entirely happy with the definition of what "a computer" is for Super User either, but if we have to draw a line, I *think* here's one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doubt this is a computer according to the (admittedly fuzzy) definition used on this site.  This is why I [raised](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2416728#2416728) attention to this question in chat. @slhck and I voted to close then.

It may have been a premature call to action, as I haven't used this device myself, but it really appeared to be little more than a simple calculator.

AFAICT, we classify quite a few products as *electronic devices* that are in both computational capabilities and modes of use much more similar to today's "computers" than this device.

Comment: The TRS-80 was most definitely a "Computer". There were (at least) 2 versions. One was the "Computer" itself with an included detachable keyboard and floppy disk drive, and 1 (perhaps more) detachable monitor. The second was an "all-in-one" version that had integrated keyboard, floppy-drives, and monitor. Other models were variations of these. They all ran versions of MS-DOS and CP/M and had built in BASIC interpreters. I think there was one model named "Color Computer" which I'm not sure of it's capabilities.

Comment: @KevinFegan Yet we do not consider modern TVs, smart phones, etc. that can have various periphery attached to them to be computers on this site. As I wrote in chat, "*We should probably close this as off topic. If my iPad is not a computer, this isn't either!*" That was my reasoning back in 2011, and I don't see a reason to revisit it now.

Comment: I understand, that's your story and you're sticking to it, regardless of accuracy. I object to your classification that it's "little more than a simple calculator". It is (was) as much of a computer as Apple II, IBM-PC, IBM-XT ... It's not a "calculator" or a game console. Do you consider those "NOT Computers" either? And comparison to a phone or iPad is unrealistic since those are not "Personal Computers". But, you are, of course, as anyone else, entitled to your opinion. At this time, I don't expect the question will be re-opened. But that doesn't mean I can defend (or ignore) its closing.

Comment: Can you point me to the `"(admittedly fuzzy) definition [of a computer] used on this site."`